# How to use 'grunt-shell' and 'grunt-shell-spawn' in the same project?

Tags: plugins, gruntjs

I want to use two similar grunt plugins [grunt-shell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell) and [grunt-shell-spawn](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell-spawn) in the same project. Because I want to run:

1. some tasks asynchronous with grunt-shell-spawn
2. some repeated tasks with grunt-shell(because grunt-shell-spawn has [problems for this requirement](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn/issues/25))

But they use the same config name, both "shell":

```
shell: {
   sometask: {}
}
```

They will be confused. How can I use different task name so I can use them both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`grunt.task.renameTask`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.renametask) will help you. Because of `grunt.loadNpmTasks` is a synchronous function, this code will do the trick:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell-spawn');
grunt.task.renameTask('shell', 'shellSpawn');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
...
```